# In .net how to tell if a Microsoft Windows 11 app, like the snipping tool, is running

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Microsoft has changed their snipping tool with Windows 11.  It has the same name 'SnippingTool.exe" as in W10, but is in a different loction and has different behaviours.

Regardless, what I'm trying to figure out is how to determine programmatically if it is running.

With the W10 version, the following works great:

```
Dim IsSnippingToolRunning as Boolean = (Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("snippingtool").Length > 0)
```

It does not however work for the W11 version.

I've tried looking at all the running process names when it is running, but can't see one
that corresponds to the W11 snipping tool being active (although it is when I do the check).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `ScreenClippingHost.exe` is the process name you want. I was able to find this quickly using the excellent [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer):

1. Launch Process Explorer
2. Open Snipping Tool with `ctrl+shift+S`
3. Close Snipping Tool with `esc`
4. Pause Process Explorer's refreshing with `space`, then look for recently-launched processes (highlighted in green):

[image]

Comment: This approach won't work if the OP wants stronger guarantees that the process really is the Windows snipping tool instead of someone running any random process from an `.exe` file renamed to `ScreenClippingHost.exe`.

Comment: (Reilly) Thank you, I don't know how I missed that!  (Dai) For the app I am writing I am not concerned about someone calling another process by that name.  But its a valid point you have.